# Thread that is not UiThread

Tags: android, serversocket, ui-thread

I am using a `Thread` to start my `ServerSocket` and I with transactions that take longer than 500ms.

I think that triggers some "App is not responding" messages.

I tried to create a thread that to separate it from the `UiThread`.

Here is my code:

```
Thread socketServerThread=new Thread(new ServerSocketThread());
        socketServerThread.start();

public class ServerSocketThread extends Thread {
    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My app crashes when I open it.

How can I solve those errors?

My LogCat:

```
04-11 21:57:23.864: E/AndroidRuntime(11761): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
04-11 21:57:23.864: E/AndroidRuntime(11761): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-11 21:57:23.864: E/AndroidRuntime(11761):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-11 21:57:23.864: E/AndroidRuntime(11761):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
04-11 21:57:23.864: E/AndroidRuntime(11761):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
04-11 21:57:23.864: E/AndroidRuntime(11761):    at com.example.imagesender.MainActivity$ServerSocketThread.run(MainActivity.java:79)
04-11 21:57:23.864: E/AndroidRuntime(11761):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: well what is the error

Comment: no stacktrace, no answer.

Comment: added logcat in post.

Comment: and why does ServerSocketThread extend Thread? it should implement Runnable...

Comment: i know hot to send runnable only with this code  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

Comment: but i dont want it to be in UiThread

Comment: dude, u actually create two threads, lol

Comment: Putting the runOnUiThread() pattern around your toast should solve the problem of doing that on the UI thread while keeping your network operations in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are trying to show a toast from a non UI thread which you cannot do, remove that and it should work.

If you want to show the toast then you have to use a handler to call back to the main thread or better yet use an `AsyncTask`

Comment: thanks i will try do some code and try if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and implement actions you need to run on UI thread in onProgressUpdate and/or in onPostExecute functions.

Also you can use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to execute a piece of code on UI Thread like that
`

```
public void run() {
    // custom thread actions
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // code that should be run on UI Thread
        }
    });
    // custom thread actions
}
```

`

P.S.: everytime you get a crash — take a look at ***adb logcat*** output first and google any error messages about your program.